# Prove that under some condition the commutator subgroup contains not only commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Let's assume $ G $ is a finite group. Let $ Z(G) $ denote its center, $(G : Z(G))$ the index of $ Z(G) $ in $ G $ and $ [G; G] $ the commutator subgroup of $ G $. Prove that if

$$ (G : Z(G)) ^2 < \left| [G; G] \right| $$

then $ [G; G] $ cannot consist of commutators (elements of form $ g^{-1}h^{-1}gh $) only.

I don't really know where to begin with - finding an example of a group which's commutator subgroup isn't just commutators is not obvious and frankly not very helpful either. I would appreciate some help on that

Comment: You just need to prove that the number of distinct commutators is at most $|G/Z(G)|^2$, and then the result follows immediately.

Comment: So I should find an injection from the set of commutators into the set $(G/Z(G))^2$? The obvious shot would be sending $[g,h] $ to $(gZ(G),hZ(G))$, but I have no clue why that would be an injection - I'm not even sure whether it's a well defined function. I tried writing it all down, but nothing came out useful

Comment: I get it already - for any $ y,z \in Z(G) ~~ [g,h] = [gy, gz] $, so any commutator is obtained from a pair of representatives of cosets of $ Z(G) $, of which there are exactly $ (G:Z(G))^2 $

Comment: Yes that's right!!!